# Phylogeny: Hybridization between different species sharing same genus?

Tags: genetics

I am doing a cross-breeding project with *Capsicum chinense* x *Capsicum baccatum*. I'm planning to breed them until 6-8 gen.

My question: What will the completed breed be classified as? Would it be a new species or will it be considered as a strain of *chinense* or *baccatum*? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hybrids are not considered named species of either of their progenitors, but classified as hybrids of both. So they would be called *Capsicum chinense x baccatum*.

Comment: Well.... all eukaryotes are hybrids.